# serialization and deserialization of object to/from specific string

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have class hierarchy:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Location
{
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string BuildingNumber { get; set; }
}


public class Show
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}


public class Place
{
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }

    public int SectionNumber { get; set; }

    public int PlaceNumber { get; set; }
}


public class Ticket
{
    public Show Show { get; set; }

    public Location Location { get; set; }

    public Place Place { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Need to serialize to string and deserialize from string to. The string description is:

```
Location|City|Street|BuildingNumber

Show|Name|Description

Place|RowNumber|SectionNumber|PlaceNumber

Users|Id---Name|Id---Name|Id---Name|Id---Name
```

Example of the string:

```
Location|Pehiche|M.Cartaxa|199

Show|Voller concert|early music

Place|5|1|32

Users|1002---Rajesh M|1010---Pallavi A|1021---Pallavi M
```

Need to do serializer with contract:

```
public interface ITicketSerializer
{
    string Serialize(Ticket ticket);

    Ticket Deserialize(string input);
}
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: The edited post is still not a question. What prevents you from completing your _"need to ..."_?

Answer (score 1):

There can be different way to serialize/deserialize these objects . You can use reflection to do it and also you can serialize and deserialize them manually . I wrote code for manually serialize/deserialize as follow
public class User
{
public int Id { get; set; }

```
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public static String Serialize(User user) => $"{user.Id}---{user.Name}";

    public static User Deserialize(String value)
    {
        var parts = value.Split("---");
        return new User
        {
            Id = int.Parse(parts[0]),
            Name = parts[1]
        };
    }
}


public class Location
{
    public string City { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }

    public string BuildingNumber { get; set; }

    public static String Serialize(Location location) => $"{location.City}|{location.Street}|{location.BuildingNumber}";

    public static Location Deserialize(String value)
    {
        var parts = value.Split("|");
        return new Location
        {
            City = parts[0],
            Street = parts[1],
            BuildingNumber = parts[2]
        };
    }
}


public class Show
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    public static String Serialize(Show show)
    {
        return $"{show.Name}|{show.Description}";
    }

    public static Show Deserialize(String value)
    {
        var parts = value.Split("|");

        return new Show
        {
            Name = parts[0],
            Description = parts[1]
        };
    }
}


public class Place
{
    public int RowNumber { get; set; }

    public int SectionNumber { get; set; }

    public int PlaceNumber { get; set; }
    
    public static String Serialize(Place place)
    {
        return $"{place.RowNumber}|{place.SectionNumber}|{place.PlaceNumber}";
    }

    public static Place Deserialize(String value)
    {
        var parts = value.Split("|");
        return new Place
        {
            RowNumber = int.Parse(parts[0]),
            SectionNumber = int.Parse(parts[1]),
            PlaceNumber = int.Parse(parts[2]),
        };
    }
}


public class Ticket:ITicketSerializer
{
    public Show Show { get; set; }

    public Location Location { get; set; }

    public Place Place { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<User> Users { get; set; }

    public string Serialize(Ticket ticket)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     
        builder.AppendLine(Show.Serialize(ticket.Show));
        builder.AppendLine(Location.Serialize(ticket.Location));
        builder.AppendLine(Place.Serialize(ticket.Place));
        builder.AppendLine(String.Join("|", ticket.Users.Select(User.Serialize)));
        
        return builder.ToString();
    }

    public Ticket Deserialize(string input)
    {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
        
        var parts = input.Split("\n");
        
        ticket.Show = Show.Deserialize(parts[0]);
        ticket.Location = Location.Deserialize(parts[1]);
        ticket.Place = Place.Deserialize(parts[2]);
        ticket.Users = parts[3].Split("|").Select(User.Deserialize);
        
        return ticket;
    }
}

public interface ITicketSerializer
{
    string Serialize(Ticket ticket);

    Ticket Deserialize(string input);
}
```

If you have any question or comment about this code , dont hestitate to write comment